# Submitting untouched redux-form with initialValues converts react-select values to array of null

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, react-select

I'm using this guide to integrate `react-select` with `redux-form`: https://gist.github.com/leocristofani/98312e61807db8f32e720c9f97a186e5

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';

RFReactSelect.defaultProps = {
  multi: false,
  className: ""
};

RFReactSelect.propTypes = {
  input: PropTypes.shape({
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onBlur: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onFocus: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
  options: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  multi: PropTypes.bool,
  className: PropTypes.string
};

export default function RFReactSelect({ input , options, multi, className }) {
  const { name, value, onBlur, onChange, onFocus } = input;
  const transformedValue = transformValue(value, options, multi);
  return (
    <Select
      valueKey="value"
      name={name}
      value={transformedValue}
      multi={multi}
      options={options}
      onChange={multi
        ? multiChangeHandler(onChange)
        : singleChangeHandler(onChange)
      }
      onBlur={() => onBlur(value)}
      onFocus={onFocus}
      className={className}
    />
  );
}

/**
 * onChange from Redux Form Field has to be called explicity.
 */
function singleChangeHandler(func) {
  return function handleSingleChange(value) {
    func(value ? value.value : '');
  };
}

/**
 * onBlur from Redux Form Field has to be called explicity.
 */
function multiChangeHandler(func) {
  return function handleMultiHandler(values) {
    func(values.map(value => value.value));
  };
}

/**
 * For single select, Redux Form keeps the value as a string, while React Select 
 * wants the value in the form { value: "grape", label: "Grape" }
 * 
 * * For multi select, Redux Form keeps the value as array of strings, while React Select 
 * wants the array of values in the form [{ value: "grape", label: "Grape" }]
 */
function transformValue(value, options, multi) {
  if (multi && typeof value === 'string') return [];

  const filteredOptions = options.filter(option => {
    return multi 
      ? value.indexOf(option.value) !== -1
      : option.value === value;
  });

  return multi ? filteredOptions : filteredOptions[0];
}
```

This works albeit with one issue (so far).

When I set the `initialValues` of the form and submit it without touching the `react-select` component, it converts the initial values of the select from `["id1", "id2", "id3"]` to [null, null, null].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. After a month of pulling my hair over this, was finally able to solve it by starting from scratch. Being new to react, there are a lot of moving parts I had to check but failed to.

Comment: How did it work? 
Can you please share the working code if possible ?
@DigitalDouble

Comment: @LalitKushwah, What specifically is the issue that you're encountering?